# Create months since current month column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

My DF looks like below:

```
IndexData     Week_number
2022-12-28    53
2022-12-29    53
2022-12-30    53
2022-12-31    53
2023-01-01    1
2023-01-02    1
2023-01-03    1
2023-01-04    1
.........
2023-02-27    9
2023-02-28    9
2023-03-01    9
2023-03-02    9
........
2023-03-29   13
2023-03-30   13
2023-03-31   13
```

I need to create another column that will looks like below:

```
IndexData     Week_number  new_column
2022-12-28    53           -9
2022-12-29    53           -9
2022-12-30    53           -9
2022-12-31    53           -9
........
2023-01-03    1            -8
2023-01-04    1            -8
.........
2023-02-27    9            -1
2023-02-28    9            -1
2023-03-01    9            Current_month
2023-03-02    9            Current_month
........
2023-03-29   13            Current_month
2023-03-30   13            Current_month
2023-03-31   13            Current_month
```

The logic for new column is:

- it should take the last month in data set and label it as 'Current_month' and then based on index date starts to count week numbers from the most recent to the oldest date. Do you have idea how I could solve this?

Regards

Comment: how do you compute -17 or -9? How can two days apart have 8 weeks difference?

Comment: I used those number as an example. They are not correct. I made changes.

Comment: Too bad I had the correct output but now AFK. Can you provide the dataframe constructor? I can try to rewrite it

Comment: I will but can you show me your code? Maybe I will find a way too

Comment: I provided a quick answer, I'll update it when I have more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this isn't it, then please show me how you get to the desired output (I'm just throwing out random ideas at this point

```
df['weeks from max date'] = (df['IndexData'] - df['IndexData'].max()).dt.days // 7

    IndexData  Week_number  weeks from max date
0  2022-12-28           53                  -14
1  2022-12-29           53                  -14
2  2022-12-30           53                  -13
3  2022-12-31           53                  -13
4  2023-01-01            1                  -13
5  2023-01-02            1                  -13
6  2023-01-03            1                  -13
7  2023-01-04            1                  -13
8  2023-02-27            9                   -5
9  2023-02-28            9                   -5
10 2023-03-01            9                   -5
11 2023-03-02            9                   -5
12 2023-03-29           13                   -1
13 2023-03-30           13                   -1
14 2023-03-31           13                    0
```

Comment: It is almost correct but it should change values not with every month but with every week. So instead of -1 value for all February, it should separate on 4 values (-1,-2,-3,-4). But this is close

Comment: that wouldn't be a month ago in that case?

Comment: Yes. In original data set there are date for every day

Comment: updated it. If this isn't it, then please show us how you get to the required output. I'm just stabbing in the dark at this point

Comment: It's fine! You did the hardest part. Now I will simple replace value from the latest month and it will be fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Using datetime operations:

```
date = pd.to_datetime(df['IndexData'])
week = date.dt.to_period('W-SAT')
month = date.dt.to_period('M')

df['new_column'] = week.sub(week[month.eq(month.max())].min()).apply(lambda x: x.n)
```

Output:

```
     IndexData  Week_number  new_column
0   2022-12-28           53          -9
1   2022-12-29           53          -9
2   2022-12-30           53          -9
3   2022-12-31           53          -9
4   2023-01-01            1          -8
5   2023-01-02            1          -8
6   2023-01-03            1          -8
7   2023-01-04            1          -8
8   2023-02-27            9           0
9   2023-02-28            9           0
10  2023-03-01            9           0
11  2023-03-02            9           0
12  2023-03-29           13           4
13  2023-03-30           13           4
14  2023-03-31           13           4
``
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `datatime` from python to get the current date. Parse that date for the month and then insert a new column where the desired conditions are met based on the parsed month.

```
import datetime

date_is = str(datetime.datetime.now())
month_is = date_is[5:7]
```

use month_is and figure out your logic for how far a different date is from your desired current date

Comment: Thanks but I need to take the last month that exist in data set. It doesn't have to be the current that we have now. Basically I found the solution how to do it:
df['Year'] = df['IndexDate'].astype(str).str[:4]
df['Month'] = df['IndexDate'].astype(str).str[5:7]

df2 = df[['IndexDate','Week number','Year','Month']][df.Year == df['Year'].max()]

df2 = df2[['IndexDate','Week number','OpeningValue','Diff','Year','Month']][df2.Month == df2['Month'].max()]

Comment: alright. When you get a second update your post to reflect your answer so if others search something similar they can find your solution.